# How to match a combination of two strings in python to find indices of rows?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to find the indices of rows that contain a combination of several rows in python. Please find a reproducible code below.

```
  df=[['Monday, 13 January 2020','',''],['Start',13588,'Jack'],['Starting','','Finish'],['','','City 1'],['Task',13589,'Finish'],['','','Address 2'],['','','City'],['Task 3',13589,'Amanda'],['','','Address 3'],['','','City 3'],['Tuesday, 14 January 2020','',''],['Task 4',13587,'Chelsea'],['','','Address 4'],['','','City 4'],['Task 5','13586','Ibrahim'],['','','Address 5'],['','','City 5'],['Task 6',13585,'Kate'],['','','Address 6'],['','','City 6']]
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns = ['Task','ID','Supervisor']
```

Here is my attempt. For example, I want to get the indices of rows that contain both `start` and `finish` or `task` and `finish`

Here is my attempt below:

```
    findrowindex = df[df.apply(lambda row: 
row.astype(str).str.contains(r'\b(?:start&finish|task&Finishing)\b').any(), axis=1)].index
```

Comment: `&` is a regular char in regex. You need `.*` / `.*?` to match any text between two words: `r'(?is)\b(?:(?:start|task).*?finish(?:ing)?|finish.*?(?:start|task))\b'`. You say `task` and `finish`, but the regex and text contains `Finishing`, what is the requirement then?

Comment: So to be clear, your expected results are indices `2` and `4`?

Comment: Well, your code is also not quite right, you are not actually checking agains the single row strings. You can't use a regex like this here.

Comment: I think you better fix your data first before loading it into `pandas`.

Comment: My apology for the typo in my sample df. I have corrected it now.

Comment: @JvdV yes, i have corrected it now. its meant to be `finish` not `finishing`. The result is 2 and 4

Comment: `df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains("Start|Task", case=False, na=False).any() & row.astype(str).str.contains("Finish", case=False, na=False).any(), axis=1)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
import re

# required because there are integer columns in the dataframe.
df = df.astype(str)

compile_ = re.compile("^Start.*Finish.*$|^Task.*Finish.*$", re.IGNORECASE)
mask = df.apply(lambda x : True if compile_.search("".join(x)) else False, axis=1)

print(df[mask])
```

output,

```
       Task     ID Supervisor
2  Starting            Finish
4    Task 2  13589     Finish
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
m = (
    df[['Task', 'Supervisor']].agg(' '.join, axis=1)
    .str.contains(r'^(?:start.*finish|task.*finish)$', case=False)
)
```

Or you can use:

```
m = (
    df['Task'].str.contains(r'^(?:start|task)', case=False) 
    & df['Supervisor'].str.contains(r'finish$', case=False)
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df[m])

       Task     ID Supervisor
2  Starting            Finish
4    Task 2  13589     Finish
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
>>> df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains("Start|Task", case=False, na=False).any() & row.astype(str).str.contains("Finish", case=False, na=False).any(), axis=1)]
       Task     ID Supervisor
2  Starting            Finish
4    Task 2  13589  Finishing
```

That is, use `&` bitwise AND operator with two calls to `str.contains`, one searching for `Start` or `Task` in a case insensitive way (due to `case=False`), and the other searching for `Finish`.